# Scale Images in Different Resolutions XML

Tags: android, xml, scaling, resolutions

I have created 4 resolution folders and put the appropriate image sizes into each as seen in the picture below:

[image]

I have also created 8 different layout folders for various screen sizes as seen in the picture below:

[image]

As you can see in the picture below, I need to re-size the images in each according XML file so they fill the screen:

[image]

I use this code to scale down images which works fine:

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"  
    android:maxWidth="150dp" 
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

But I cannot figure out how to scale up images.  I have been trying to use this code:

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"  
    android:minWidth="150dp" 
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

Any ideas on how to scale up the images?  Thank you!!

XML:

```
    <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnPlay"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/btn_play"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"  
    android:scaleX="1.5"
    android:scaleY="1.5"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"  />
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried?:

```
android:scaleX="1.5" // 1 is 100% size
android:scaleY="1.5"
```

Comment: This works in re-sizing the actual image but the imageView does not scale with it so the pictures overlap.  Any idea on how to make the imageView scale with the image?

Comment: Yes, I have a android:layout_width="wrap_content" and android:layout_width="wrap_content" on the imageView

Comment: wrap all your image views with a layout, set w&h of the layout to match_parent, and set gravity to center/center_horizontal.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34121/discussion-between-c-and-shane)

Answer (score 1):

**try** `android:scaleType="fitXY"` **instead of**  `android:scaleType="fitCenter"`

**Edit**

**use `LinearLayout` with `layout_weight and weightSum`**

**like** adjust `WeighSum` and `layout_weight` according to your `UI` !

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="8" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3" >

        <!-- your Match m Image -->
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="#fff" >

        <!-- your play image -->
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <!-- your Multiplayer image -->
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <!-- your High score Image -->
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <!-- your how to play Image -->
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Tested, but the images still won't scale up.

Comment: @Shane use android:layout_width="match_parent" and android:layout_width="match_parent"

Comment: "match_parent" fills the entire screen with the imageView.  I have updated my question with the xml

Comment: @Shane than use linear layouts with layout_weight and weightSum

Comment: It seems like a lot of code to change just to scale up images for a different size screen.  I am considering just making xhdpi images for all resolutions and scaling them down for the other layouts.

Comment: My entire application is designed using RelativeLayout. It would be a huge pain to change all of my layouts to Linear.  I am suprised the solution to my problem is not easier because I have followed Android's instructions exactly for supporting multiple screens.

Answer (score 0):

You shall use the new size qualifiers for this. That's the best way. What you are doing is not wrong, but with so many different breed of devices it have become obsolete. Refer [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#NewQualifiers)

Comment: Size qualifiers were introduced in Android 3.2.  My application need to support at least API 8.